# What is the best way to update multuple records with different values in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For Example `{a : "x",count : 2},{a : "y",count : 5}` If i want to update count to 5 for records whose a value is x and for a = y records i need to change count to 9,then how should i update it in mongoose ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple documents can be updated against one query only (by passing {multi: true} option). But for more than one query you can use multiple calls and do the update. Try [async parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel), which will run your code in parallel.

```
async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            Model.update({a: "x"}, {count: 5}, {multi: true}, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    callback(err)
                }
                else{
                    callback(null, result);
                }
            })
        },
        function(callback) {
            Model.update({a: "y"}, {count: 9}, {multi: true}, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    callback(err)
                }
                else{
                    callback(null, result);
                }
            })
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log(results)
        }
    });
```